# how can i get return value of javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

my code like this

```
    var key,value;     
   //……some code……    
   function checkReg(i,j){    
       $.getJSON(api_checkExists,{"k":i,"v":j,"rand":Math.random()},function(c){    
           alert(c.status);    
           return(c.status);    
       });      
   }        
    var temp=checkReg(key,value);    
    alert(temp);
```

The problem is when I run it in my browser, it always fist alert undefined then alert the return value; seems like that can not get the return value of function checkReg. I was so confused, what should I do?

Comment: You will have to process the value from within `$.getJSON` is it is asynchronous. Your `return` is returning from `getJSON`'s callback function, not `checkReg`

Answer (score 4):

That's because your ajax call is running asynch from the rest. Your code will already have returned before before the ajax is even triggered.

So the returning doesn't work like that, you should provide a callback to your function instead of trying to return it.

```
function checkReg(i,j, callback){    
       $.getJSON(api_checkExists,{"k":i,"v":j,"rand":Math.random()},function(c){    
           alert(c.status);    
           callback(c.status);    
       });      
   }        
    checkReg(key,value, function(temp){
          alert(temp);   
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do that... since ajax is ashynchronus ... by the time the success function is called and return, the alert will be called thus having temp as undefined or empty.. one way to do this is doing the thing you need to inside the success called back of getJSON... or use [$.deffered](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) or callinga calback function..

```
function checkReg(i,j, callback){    
   $.getJSON(api_checkExists,{"k":i,"v":j,"rand":Math.random()},function(c){    
       callback(c.status);    
   });      
}        
checkReg(key,value, function(temp){
      alert(temp);   
});
```